# Modify value in json in bulk with regex

Tags: json, regex, bash, jq

I am quite new to using terminal, so I hope you can bear with my novice question.  I have a set of data, containing pronunciation of words in Cantonese:

```
{
    監: [gaam1],
    參: [caam1],
    三: [saam1],
    ...
}
```

And I want to search and modify them to the following:

```
{
    監: [gāam],
    參: [cāam],
    三: [sāam],
    ...
}
```

I know I can work with all objects one by one with built-in function `map` in jq, but how should I write the regex part to get this result?  As the value in each object is different and value I want to replace is different for each object, can this be done with regex?

Comment: Is it always the same manipulation? Remove the last character and accent the first "a"? If not, how are you determining how to change?

Comment: Please post valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following input:

```
{"監":["gaam1"],"參":["caam1"],"三":["saam1"]}
```

the following filter would do the job:

```
map_values( map(sub( "aam1$"; "āam") ))
```

For additional substitutions, you could just extend the `sub` pipeline as far as necessary, along the lines of:

```
map_values( map( sub(_;_) | sub(_;_) | sub(_;_) ))
```

If the `sub` pipeline is very long, it might be better to construct a long if/then/else/end 
statement:

```
if endswith("aam1") then sub("aam1$"; "āam")
elif ....
else .
end
```

### More ambitious regexes

Consider for example:

```
sub( "aa(?<x>[a-z])1"; "āa\(.x)")
```